# Noto Font not working with jsPDF using Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, jspdf, custom-font

I am trying to generate a PDF that can handle every language with jsPDF. The problem here is that I can't add the font to jsPDF.

This is what I did.

1. Got the font from [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) (So far I tried with NotoSans regular and NotoSerif Regular)
2. Converted the .ttf file in many ways using different converters, but mainly the one recomended in the [Github documentation](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/README.md#use-of-utf-8--ttf)
   which is their [fontconverter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html).
3. Modified the file to export the font like this: `export const Noto = '[Encoded string]';` and saved it as `NotoSerif-Regular-normal.js`
4. Added the import in my Vue file.`import Noto from "@/fonts/Noto/NotoSerif-Regular-normal.js";`
5. Add the font to jsPDF.

   ```
   doc.addFileToVFS("Noto.ttf", Noto);
   doc.addFont("Noto.ttf", "Noto", "normal");
   doc.setFont("Noto", "normal");
   doc.setFontSize(16);
   ```

But hen I try to create the PDF, I get the following error:

```
jsPDF PubSub Error Font does not exist in vFS, import fonts or remove declaration doc.addFont('Noto.ttf'). 
Error: Font does not exist in vFS, import fonts or remove declaration doc.addFont('Noto.ttf').
```

Any idea of what is happening? I already tried jsPDF and jsPDF.Debug and they are not working with this font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to do some changes to achieve this. first of all, the [font converter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) was not working properly for me. I had to use this [Base64 Converter](https://www.base64encode.org/)
and this solved my first issue.

The second issue that I had, was the missing curly brackets in the import, so I edited it like this:

```
import { Noto } from "@/fonts/Noto/NotoSerif-Regular-normal.js";
```

This solved completely my problem.